# How can I traverse a particular td column in an html table and replace the innerText to change the date format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, momentjs

I have a table without IDs or class names:

```
<table id="tableexample">
<tr>
<td>example</td>
<td>Oct 3 2019 12:00AM</td>
<td>another</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I am trying to replace the innerText of every nth td for every single row. I have successfully been able to convert the td to the right format by using

```
var somedate = document.querySelector("#_tableexample > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)").innerText;
moment(somedate,'MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').toISOString();}
```

and I need to iterate through each row and display the date in that format. It is for the purpose of generating ISO 8601 for event schema markup.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You say `I have a table without IDs or class names` but why does you table then have an ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select all `tr`, not `tr:nth-child(3)` only, then apply your function to the collection:

```
var somedate = document.querySelectorAll("#tableexample tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");
somedate.forEach(function(item) {
    // do whatever you need
    moment(item.innerText,'MMM DD YYYY h:mm:a').toISOString();
});
```